# Finite intersection property in any metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If $(X,d)$ is any metric space and $\{A_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ is a collection of nonempty compact subsets of $X$ such that the intersection of any finite subcollection of sets is non empty does that imply that $\bigcap A_\alpha $ is non empty?

I tried to prove this by assuming that it is empty and using the complements of $ A_\alpha $ as an open covering but wasn't sure how to get a contradiction if the statement is true in the first place.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to elaborate your statement **I tried to prove this by assuming that it is empty and using the complements of $A_{\alpha}$ as an open covering but wasn't sure how to get a contradiction if the statement is true in the first place.**

Comment: I assumed that $\bigcap A_\alpha $is empty, then the complement of $\bigcap A_\alpha$=X therefore $\bigcup \overline A_\alpha$ =X and therefore is an open covering of any subset of X, I thought it could be used to obtain a contradiction using the compactness of some set but I couldn't do it...I used ($\overline A_\alpha$ to indicate the compliments as I wasn't sure of how to use 'c')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} A_{\alpha}$ is empty. Then, by De Morgan's law, $X=\bigcup_{\alpha\in I} A_{\alpha}^c$. Pick any $\alpha_0\in I$ (tacitly assuming that the index set $I$ is not empty). It follows that $A_{\alpha_0}\subseteq \bigcup_{\alpha\in I} A_{\alpha}^c=X$. Since $A_{\alpha_0}$ is compact and $\{A_{\alpha}^c\}_{\alpha\in I}$ is an open cover of it, there exist some $n\in\mathbb N$ and $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\in I$ such that $A_{\alpha_0}\subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^n A_{\alpha_j}^c$. But this implies that $\bigcap_{j=0}^n A_{\alpha_j}=\varnothing$, a contradiction to the assumption that finite intersections are not empty.

Comment: can you explain why $A_{\alpha_0}\subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^n A_{\alpha_j}^c$. implies that $\bigcap_{j=0}^n A_{\alpha_j}=\varnothing$ please?

Comment: @user68099 Suppose that $x\in A_{\alpha_0}$. Then, since $A_{\alpha_0}\subseteq\bigcup_{j=1}^n A_{\alpha_j}^c$, it follows that $x\in A_j^c$ for some $j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. In other words, if $x$ is in $A_{\alpha_0}$, then it must be missing from at least one of $A_{\alpha_1},\ldots,A_{\alpha_n}$. In particular, this means that no element can be in all of $A_{\alpha_0},A_{\alpha_1},\ldots,A_{\alpha_n}$, so that $\bigcap_{j=0}^{n}A_{\alpha_j}$ is empty. Does it make sense?

Comment: yes it does thank you

Comment: You're welcome. One remark: $X$ need not even be a metric space; it is sufficient to assume it's Hausdorff (which ensures that compact subsets are closed so that their complements are open).